# Optimizing Cython: 5-byte string or size_t?

Tags: c, optimization, cython

I'm writing a Cython module that deals with large numbers of 5-byte keys retrieved from a key-value store. I settled on 5 because it gives me enough room for combinations (~5 trillion) for very little space.

Result sets are retrieved and combined in contiguous memory blocks that I can scan by 5-byte strides. It's pretty fast so far, but the code could use some cleanup.

I am wondering if I can simplify my code by using size_t or long ints instead of 5-byte units, and deal with arrays of numbers instead of byte blocks. Aside from the 5- to 8-byte storage increase, I wonder what performance penalty I might incur into, or if I may even make my program more efficient on a 64-bit machine if some processor instructions favor 8-byte units.

I am quite new to this kind of low-level programming so I thought I could use some advice before I start to write a proof of concept that covers all the operations that I need to do (lookup, concatenating, inserting, etc).

Tips are appreciated!

Comment: `size_t` may not be 8 bytes... like on a 32-bit architecture, where it's likely to be 4 bytes.  If you want something that's ≥ 8 bytes use an `int64_t` or `int_least64_t` or `int_fast64_t`, or one of the unsigned versions.  But yes, an integer type would probably be better; as it is you've got a pointer (which is probably 8 bytes on your system, seeing as `size_t` is 8 bytes) to 5 bytes of data, why not cut out the middle-man?

Comment: Thanks for catching the size_t part—yes, that can be 4 bytes (and maybe I could exploit that to scale the application down on 32-bit architectures). I am not concerned about the pointer though. I have usually one pointer that I move around a large page. The most expensive operations are `memcpy`ing the keys from the results, assembling them in a specific order and appending them to the allocated result block.

Comment: you can simply use `uint32_t` as long as you take care while doing things with it, like using `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`, or copy it to a `char[5]` and NULL terminate it before printing with standard functions